# How to get fields and properties in order as declared in class?

Tags: c#, reflection

I need to get fields and properties in order as declared in class.

Here is my existing code:

```
MemberInfo[] l_arrMemberInfoTemp = m_target.GetType().GetMembers(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

From MSDN [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getmember?view=netframework-4.7.2) says, *The GetMember method does not return members in a particular order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not depend on the order in which members are returned, because that order varies.*

The above code returns all properties first and then all fields.

**MyClass.cs**

```
int myInt;
int myIntProp{get;set;}
float myFloat;
int myFloatProp{get;set;}
```

**Current output:**

```
myIntProp         <----- Property comes first.
myFloatProp       <----- Property comes first.
myInt
myFloat
```

**Expected output:**

```
myInt
myIntProp
myFloat
myFloatProp
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Why do you need them in that order?

Comment: @stuartd. I am writing an editor UI in Unity3D for which i need to get fields & properties in correct order.

Comment: Why do you want the order? There's none as far as the compiler is concerned. The IL metadata doesn't depend on the file order either

Comment: @SatbirSingh the UI editor in Visual Studio Winforms for example doesn't depend on any order. There's no "correct" order anyway

Comment: If you want to get the same information the compiler gets you should use a Roslyn analyzer, not reflection. Roslyn allows you to modify the code as well. The fixes and refactorings in Visual Studio are built using Roslyn.

Comment: Thanks Guys. seems link there is no easy way.